# Javascript: Regular expression to remove extra space between <iframe> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, iframe

I have a string containing `<iframe>` tag. The string is dynamic and contains iframe like:

```
<iframe src="abc.com"></iframe> OR
<iframe src="abc.com"> </iframe> OR
<iframe src="abc.com">  </iframe> OR
```

I would like to convert `>  </iframe>` in to the `></iframe>`

I have tried to remove the space using below code but it is not working fine.

```
var str = '<iframe src="abc.com">     </iframe>';    
alert( str.replace("/\s/g", "") );
```

Please let me know if there any solution for this?

Comment: Regular expressions are not strings, try `replace( /\s/g, "" )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to replace all the spaces - you only want to replace the spaces *inside* the `iframe` tag, so `/\s/g` won't work. Try this instead:

```js
const htmlStr = `<iframe src="abc.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="abc.com"> </iframe>
<iframe src="abc.com">  </iframe>`;
console.log(
  htmlStr.replace(/\s+(?=<\/iframe>)/g, '')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing in a regex correctly. In javascript regexs are part of the language, so you don't need the quotes.

`str.replace(/\s/g, "")`